# Is there a way to create a Type Guard function for possibly undefined object and check a field and infer the parent object is not undefined?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Say I have an object that may be undefined, is there a way to make a Type Guard function so that if I use optional chaining to check if a field is valid, that TypeScript can infer the object itself is also a defined value?

```
function isNotUndefined<T>(
    arg: T
): arg is Exclude<T, undefined> {
    return arg !== "undefined";
}

let someVal: { foo: "string"; bar: "string" } | undefined;

if (isNotUndefined(someVal?.foo)) {
    console.log(someVal.foo); // Throws Error: TS18048: 'someVal' is possibly 'undefined'.
}

if (someVal?.foo !== undefined) {
    console.log(someVal.foo);
}
```

In the second instance my IDE (Webstorm) still warns me that `someVal` might not have been initialized, but it other than that it doesn't throw an Error. I've tried updating the typing for the `isNotUndefined` to be `unknown` instead of T, but that doesn't work either. Ideally, I'd like to come up with a way to make this work with the `isNotUndefined` function, as we use that for type guarding all over, not just in the case of objects, and I'd hate to have to make a separate version of this function exclusively for objects...

Comment: That does answer my question, yeah. Sad that it's not possible yet :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of TypeScript 5.1, this is not currently possible, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#34974](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34974).  Right now a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) only acts on an argument if it's a variable or direct object property access expression.  But `someVal?.foo` is neither of those, so it doesn't do any narrowing.

There is some hope that this could change, though.  The issue is marked as [Help Wanted](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/labels/Help%20Wanted), meaning that pull requests addressing it are welcome (subject to [the guidelines for contributing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cd391b066b49cead0d1b1ec089ab4f4de59a16d1/CONTRIBUTING.md#instructions-for-contributing-code)).  Anyone who cares enough about this to see it implemented should therefore consider doing so themselves!